# RK4 code using Cython is not working faster than usual python

Tags: python, cython

I want to write a simple code to solve coupled differential equation using Runge-Kutta mothod. The code written in python is taking too long, therefore, I wrote it using Cython, which is

```
import time
import cython
cimport numpy as np

def f(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] state, float t):
    cdef float x, p
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] du
    x = state[0]; p = state[1];
    du = np.array([p,-x])
    return du

def motion(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] u0, np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] t):
    cdef float dt, tmax, t0
    dt = t[1]-t[0]; tmax = t[-1]; t0 = t[0]
    cdef int nt = int((tmax-t0)/(dt));
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Xt = np.array((nt+1)*[list(u0)[0]]), Pt = np.array((nt+1)*[list(u0)[1]]), u
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] k1,k2,k3,k4

    u = u0
    for ii in range(0,nt):
        #print(i)
        k1 = dt * f(u, t[ii])
        k2 = dt * f(u + 0.5 * k1, t[ii] + 0.5*dt)
        k3 = dt * f(u + 0.5 * k2, t[ii] + 0.5*dt)
        k4 = dt * f(u + k3, t[ii] + dt)
        #u[ii+1] = u[ii] + (k1 + 2*(k2 + k3) + k4)/6.0

        Xt[ii+1] = Xt[ii] + (k1 + 2*(k2 + k3) + k4)[0]/6.0
        Pt[ii+1] = Pt[ii] + (k1 + 2*(k2 + k3) + k4)[1]/6.0

        u = np.array( [ Xt[ii+1],Pt[ii+1] ] )

    return Xt,Pt
```

This code is compiling correctly, however it is taking same amount of time to compile as original python code. How to correct the code?